# Copied Workspace, now Problem with rosdep

Tags: python, rosdep, update, filesystem, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I accidentally deleted my plattform but could save my workspace somehow. Now i set up a new Ros Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04 same stuff as before. I copied my data in my new workspace and sourced the setup.bash.

Now I am trying to "make" again the nodes to be usable on the new system but when I am doing make it says:

```
moviplc@moviplc:~$ source ~/indigo_ws/setup.bash 
moviplc@moviplc:~$ roscd twist_to_odom/


moviplc@moviplc:~/indigo_ws/sandbox/roche_control/twist_to_odom$ make
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package twist_to_odom
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rospack deps-manifests twist_to_odom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 58, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 127, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 607, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 504, in load_cached_sources_list
    with open(cache_index, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/moviplc/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
[rospack] Error: could not call python function 'rosdep2.rospack.init_rospack_interface'


CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  

  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'twist_to_odom'.
  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
  broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:207 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/moviplc/indigo_ws/sandbox/roche_control/twist_to_odom/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** [all] Fehler 1
```

I have really no idea whats happening, he seems to have some kind of problem with rosdep?
I hope anybody can help me I am really broke :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217391/copied-workspace,-now-problem-with-rosdep/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/moviplc/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
> ```

Seems your current user doesn't have access to `~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index`. Did you copy your entire home dir to your new system? If so, it could be that the `rosdep` cache is owned by your old user (the username may be the same, but the `uid` most likely isn't).

Can you check what the output is of `ls -al ~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index`?

A quick fix would be to remove the entire `~/.ros/rosdep` dir, then do a `rosdep update`. If the permissions of `~/.ros` are ok, that should get `rosdep` to recreate its cache - with the proper permissions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0